# grouping counted data by column name

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

1. QuranMaster

[image]

2.QuranPrayed

[image]

I just wanted to have all the siparas and there count as result.

Means expected result is as follows:

```
Sipara1      3
Sipara2      2
..
..
..
```

Sipara1 is 3 because it has arrived 3 times in QuranPrayed.

I made following query:

```
select qm.sipara,COUNT(qp.Sipara) from QuranMaster qm,QuranPrayed qp 
where qp.sipara=qm.sipara
group by qm.sipara
```

This query works perfectly right when QuranPrayed has values.

But when QuaranPrayed has no values, it does not shows me result.

My expectation is:

```
Sipara1      0
Sipara2      0
..
..
..
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, Prayed = COUNT(qp.Sipara) 
FROM    QuranMaster qm
        LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp 
            ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
GROUP BY qm.sipara;
```

It is worth noting that the implicit join syntax you have used is over 20 years old and was replaced in ANSI 92 with explicit joins. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) raises some very valid reasons to switch to the newer syntax. Probably the most pertinant of which to you is the use of LEFT JOIN. previously in SQL-Server your query would have been:

```
select qm.sipara,COUNT(qp.Sipara) 
from QuranMaster qm,QuranPrayed qp 
where qp.sipara=*qm.sipara
group by qm.sipara
```

However this is deprecated and you will likely get the following error:

> The query uses non-ANSI outer join operators ("*=" or "=*"). To run this query without modification, please set the compatibility level for current database to 80, using the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE. It is strongly recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN). In the future versions of SQL Server, non-ANSI join operators will not be supported even in backward-compatibility modes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select qm.sipara, COUNT(qp.Sipara) ReadSparas 
from QuranMaster qm LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp 
ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
group by qm.sipara
```

Comment: How do you sum a (var)char?

Comment: I thought There was a column with the number of times it been read.